# How do i define an enum in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, enums, graphql

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is send info to the server without quotations e.g Admin instead of "Admin", but as we all know Graphql will throw an error is the variable is not defined or is not in quotations.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

we can create a enum like property as below:

```
const adminEnum = { Admin: 'Admin'};
```

Hope I got the question right.

Comment: This is not a type. The answer below is thus a better choice in typescript (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65108763/9611924)

Answer (score 3):

you can use enum with `typeScript` in `react-native` like describe in the [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

sample code is

```
enum Direction {
  Up = 1,
  Down,
  Left,
  Right,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Enum in React as below `method` is Enum type in GraphQL

```
const result = apolloclient.mutate({
       mutation: reset_password,
       variables: {
           method: 'EMAIL',
           uuid: opts.uuid
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

enum Pole {
East = 1,
West,
North,
South,
}

Answer (score 0):

In a seperate class and a file.

```
  export enum TransportTypeEnum {
      OneWay = 0,
      Return = 1,
    }
```

import it to other class like

```
import {TransportTypeEnum} from '../enums/TransportTypeEnum';
```